# How do i print element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $print_layout;
$print_layout += '<div class="main_print">';
for($i=0;$i<=totalTokenNumer;$i++){
    $print_layout += '<div class="print_block">';
    $print_layout += $randomText[$i];
    $print_layout += '</div>';
}
$print_layout += '</div>';
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = $print_layout;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

This is my code to print  random text in some design. But i want to print `$print_layout` variable directly with out below code is this possible?

```
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = $print_layout;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

If yes, how can i print it.

Comment: You don't print variables. Not clear what you are asking. Please read [ask] and update question with a proper explanation

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to open the print dialog, with the text generated from your function, without changing the appearance of the page being viewed. in that case,
create an iframe, set the iframe contents to the result of your function, and call print on the iframe's window.

Answer (score 1):

you can control what parts of the page are visible in the print preview using `@media print` media query

[working example with textarea contents](https://jsfiddle.net/c1mpb7h4/)

[example using a variant of your object to be printed](https://jsfiddle.net/c1mpb7h4/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">


<p>
click the button to print whatever is in the textbox. 
</p>
<textarea id="print-contents">
  this content will be printed

</textarea>
<p>
<button id="print-button">print</button>
</p>

</div>

<div id='print-view'>
xcvxvcxvc
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var printButton  = document.getElementById('print-button');
var printView = document.getElementById('print-view');
var printContents = document.getElementById('print-contents');

printButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
var toPrint = printContents.innerHTML;

printView.innerHTML = toPrint;
window.print();
});
```

**CSS**

```
#print-view{
  display:none;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}

#print-contents{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}

@media print{

#print-view{
  display:block;

}

#page {
   visibility:hidden;
}

}
```